# Why are some students seeing a blurred homework assignment in Google Classrooms?

Tags: google-classroom

I created an assignment in Google Classrooms (each student gets a copy of it), and a small number of students can't see the link to the assignment. It appears blurred as follows:

[image]

What's going on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since a copy of the assignment will be made in the student's Google space (the copy of the document will be owned by the student), the student must have available space. If they have exceeded their quota on Google Drive, they must [free up space](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/6374270?hl=en) to be able to "see" the assignment.

Sadly, no error is displayed in Classroom, so it is a usability bug.

Perhaps the bug exists because at the time Classroom was coded (pre pandemic?), the developers never thought universities would have imposed quotas on their Google drives. In 2022 Google changed their policies (prices) for universities, and limits are now a reality. Hopefully Google will fix the "blur" to actually be a useful error message.